# Whats the vulnerability in this Java Code?

Tags: java, security

[Vulnerability Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuDck.png)

a.  What kind of vulnerability this code have? Why?

b.  Give a simple sample code to exploit it.

I am new to some cybersecurity questions and do not know how to approach one such as this. Any help on this problem, along with places I should look to learn more about cybersecurity as a whole is appreciated. I am somewhat versed in use at Kali but lack in this programming knowledge based questions.

ps. I am new to Stack Exchange, help me if I posted this in the wrong section

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like it would be better off on https://security.stackexchange.com/. That being said, please post code as text rather than images or any off-site resources. An image can not be copied, searched or experimented with. Additionally, you are more likely to get a response when you show the research and attempts you made.

Comment: Hi Joshua, you’re new and it’s great to have new members but some things are a no-no, such as: images of code and “what’s wrong with x” questions. So I’m afraid it’s a little on the broad side for SO.

Answer (score 1):

You do not parse arguments which user can provide. This vulnerability name is [Command Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection). Example from [`Command injection in Java`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_injection_in_Java):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Example2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException {
        if(args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("No arguments");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] cmd = new String[3];
        cmd[0] = "cmd.exe" ;
                cmd[1] = "/C";
                cmd[2] = "dir " + args[0];
        Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);

        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code could be injected by chaining multiple commands together.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious security risk would be that you just take every parameter from the commandline and execute it regardless of what it will be. So the user can execute everything not only making a new directory but actually what she wants.